# Postgres Error: More than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression. 21000

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I'm trying to insert distinct rows into a table however, I'm receiving the error in the title. What I don't understand is that I have set the LIMIT to 1 as I assumed this would solve the issue.

Can anyone please shed some light on this?

> ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression.

```
 INSERT INTO reports.sem_attribution_v2
SELECT DISTINCT
  tsa.user_id,
  tsa.transfer_date,
  tsa.engine,
  tsa.campaign_id,
  tsa.adgroup_id,
  (CASE
    WHEN tsa.engine = 'quora' THEN NULL
    WHEN tsa.source ILIKE '%uac%' THEN (
      SELECT
        account
      FROM reports.lookup_uac_elements
      WHERE campaign_id = tsa.campaign_id
      LIMIT 1)
    WHEN tsa.engine = 'google' THEN (
      SELECT
        pse.account_name
      FROM reports.lookup_paid_search_elements pse
      WHERE pse.campaign_id = tsa.campaign_id
      AND pse.adgroup_id = tsa.adgroup_id
      LIMIT 1)
    WHEN tsa.engine = 'bing' THEN (
      SELECT
        lbe.account_name
      FROM reports.lookup_bing_elements lbe
      WHERE lbe.campaign_id = tsa.campaign_id
      AND lbe.adgroup_id = tsa.adgroup_id
      LIMIT 1
    )
    ELSE NULL
   END) as account_name,
  (
    CASE
      WHEN tsa.engine = 'quora' THEN NULL
      WHEN tsa.source ILIKE '%uac%' THEN (
        SELECT
          lue.campaign
        FROM reports.lookup_uac_elements lue
        WHERE lue.campaign_id = tsa.campaign_id
      )
      WHEN tsa.engine = 'google' THEN (
        SELECT
          pse.campaign_name
        FROM reports.lookup_paid_search_elements pse
        WHERE pse.campaign_id = tsa.campaign_id
        AND pse.adgroup_id = tsa.adgroup_id
        LIMIT 1
      )
      WHEN tsa.engine = 'bing' THEN (
        SELECT
          lbe.campaign_name
        FROM reports.lookup_bing_elements lbe
        WHERE lbe.campaign_id = tsa.campaign_id
        AND lbe.adgroup_id = tsa.adgroup_id
        LIMIT 1
      )
      ELSE NULL
    END
  ) as campaign_name,
  (CASE
    WHEN tsa.engine = 'quora' THEN NULL
    WHEN tsa.source ILIKE '%uac%' THEN NULL
    WHEN tsa.engine = 'google' THEN (
      SELECT
        pse.adgroup_name
      FROM reports.lookup_paid_search_elements pse
      WHERE pse.campaign_id = tsa.campaign_id
      AND pse.adgroup_id = tsa.adgroup_id
      LIMIT 1
    )
    WHEN tsa.engine = 'bing' THEN (
      SELECT
        lbe.adgroup_name
      FROM reports.lookup_bing_elements lbe
      WHERE lbe.campaign_id = tsa.campaign_id
      AND lbe.adgroup_id = tsa.adgroup_id
      LIMIT 1
    )
    ELSE NULL
   END) as adgroup_name,
  tsa.creation_platform,
  tsa.profile_country,
  tsa.ltr_12m,
  tsa.costs_12m,
  tsa.ltv_12m,
  tsa.first_paid_touch,
  tsa.even_weights,
  tsa.first_team_touch,
        (CASE
            WHEN tsa.profile_type = 'business' THEN 1
            ELSE 0
         END) as business,
  tsa.content,
  tsa.ltr_12m_r,
  tsa.costs_12m_r,
  tsa.ltv_12m_r,
        (CASE
            WHEN tsa.profile_type = 'consumer' THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END) as consumer
FROM tmp_sem_attribution tsa;
```

Comment: This subquery doesn't have a LIMIT: `(
        SELECT
          lue.campaign
        FROM reports.lookup_uac_elements lue
        WHERE lue.campaign_id = tsa.campaign_id
      )`

Comment: You have 8 "scalar subqueries". Scalar subqueries must return a single row, never multiple rows. Make sure the filtering condition of each one **never** returns more than one row.

Comment: Thanks @eurotrash I completely missed that one out. It has now solved the issue.
TheImpaler thanks for the advice, noted :)